# http connection between ReactSample and AsP.NET Core WebApi

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I am using axios for http request.
in frontend

```
async componentDidMount() {
const { data: posts } =await axios.get("http://localhost:58944/api/posts");
this.setState({ posts });
}
```

and in backend .request from frontend is received.and in console browser look like below.
[image]

setting in backend from cors is done:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ReactCorsPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                                                                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                                                                   .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000/")
                                                                   .AllowCredentials()
                                                                   .Build());
        });
```

in ConfigureServices and in Configure function

```
  app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("ReactCorsPolicy");

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

and error in this picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your CORS settings. But in the second line of the errors in your posted image, you have a `server-side` error. In this case, ASP.NET Core ***will not*** set the CORS headers. That's why you think your CORS settings is wrong, which isn't. Take look at the debug window of Visual Studio or the Console window to see the generated logs of the application and then try to fix that server-side error. Also try to open the `http://localhost:58944/api/posts` address with your browser directly to see if it's working or not.

Comment: I resolve this problem.a problem is WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000/").I remove '/' from  WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000"). and work.best regard

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues using the C# CORS functions. Try setting a proxy in your packages.json file.

[Here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) is a great link showing some ways you can set it up for local development.

Hope this helps!